# -keep option in proguard-rules.pro

Tags: android, proguard

sorry for the beginner level question because I am also beginner.So this question helpful for others.

My Java Class is :

```
   public class Dog{
   String breed;
   int ageC
   String color;

   void barking(){
   }

   void hungry(){
   }

   void sleeping(){
   }
}
```

proguard keep line for this object

```
-keep public class mypackageName.Dog
```

my question is after compile class Dog's member variables and method obfuscated or not??

sorry for the bad English :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u use the keep option it wont be obfuscated .
like

```
-keep class mypackageName.Dog.** { *; }
```

Comment: I did this like **-keep class mypackageName.Dog {void barking(); void hungry(); void sleeping()}**

thanx for help #ankitagrawal